# spfx webpart react rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I am using REST API in my SPFx web-part and passing parameter in REST API but its not working as expected , there is some mistake in writing REST API within `` as parameter is not working:

```
export default class ReactGetItems extends React.Component<IReactGetitemsProps, IReactGetItemsState> 
{
state: IReactGetItemsState

constructor(props: IReactGetitemsProps)
{ 
super(props);

this.state = 
{ 
items: [ 
{ 

  "ImageLink":"", 
  "Template": "",  
  "DataGroupTemplate":"",
  "DataGroupTemplate_x003a_Te": "" ,
  "CurrentReportLink"   : "" ,
  "CurrentNonReportLink"    : "" ,
  "HistoricalReportLink"    : "",
  "HistoricalNonReportLink": "" ,





}],

items2: [ 
  { 
    "Title" :"" ,
    "DataGroupTemplate_x003a_Te": "" ,
    "CurrentReportLink" : "" ,
    "CurrentNonReportLink"  : "" ,
    "HistoricalReportLink"  : "" ,
    "HistoricalNonReportLink": "" ,

  }],

  items3:[ 
    { 
      "Title" :"" ,
  "DataGroupTemplate_x003a_Te": "" ,
  "CurrentReportLink"   : "" ,
  "CurrentNonReportLink"    : "" ,
  "HistoricalReportLink"    : "" ,
  "HistoricalNonReportLink": "" ,


    }]   

}; 


ShowGrid(a)
{ 
  var reactHandler = this; 
  var currentuser ='';

  jquery.ajax({ 
  url:`${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/currentuser`,
  type: "GET", 
  headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
  success: function(resultData) { 
          currentuser=resultData.d.Email;
          no();
    reactHandler.setState({
    }); 
  }, 
  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
  } 
  });
  function no()
  {
  var ak =`${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserList')/items?$select=UserName/EMail,UserType&$filter=UserName/EMail eq  '${currentuser}' &$expand=UserName`;
  console.log(ak)
  jquery.ajax({ 
    url:ak,
    type: "GET", 
    headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
    success: function(resultData) { 
      console.log(resultData)  
      if(resultData.d.results.length!=0)
      {


          jquery.ajax({ 
            url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Templates')/items?$select=Title,CurrentReportLink,HistoricalReportLink,DataGroupTemplate/Template&$expand=DataGroupTemplate&$filter=DataGroupTemplate/Template eq '${a}'`, 
            type: "GET", 
            headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
            success: function(resultData) {   

            reactHandler.setState({ 

            items2: resultData.d.results 

            }); 

            }, 
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            } 
            });  




      }

      else
      {


          jquery.ajax({ 

            url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Templates')/items?$select=Title,CurrentReportLink,HistoricalReportLink,DataGroupTemplate/Template&$expand=DataGroupTemplate&$filter=DataGroupTemplate/Template eq '${a}'`, 
            type: "GET", 
            headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
            success: function(resultData) {   

            reactHandler.setState({ 

            items3: resultData.d.results 

            }); 

            }, 
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            } 
            });  



      }
    reactHandler.setState({

    }); 
    },
   error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    console.log("Eroror")
    } 
  }); 

    }
  } 

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactGetitemsProps> {
return ( 

  {this.state.items.map((items,key)=>
{    
return(
<DocumentCard styles={cardStyles} onClick={() =>this.ShowGrid(items.Template)}>
<DocumentCardTitle styles={Documentcardstyle} title={items.Template} />
<DocumentCardImage  styles={Documentcardstyle} height={100}imageFit={ImageFit.cover}  imageSrc={items.ImageLink ? items.ImageLink["Url"] : ''} />
<DocumentCardDetails>
</DocumentCardDetails>
</DocumentCard>);
  })}
)}
```

Comment: Is you variable name is **`a`**?

Comment: yes variable name is a

Comment: please post the complete function.

Comment: a lot of code is missing here. If as you say, "this" is not working, you should show the component or at least, say if is a react function component or class. Show that at least....

Comment: Can you show the component class  or the function declaration? I mean, is like this: `function Welcome(props) {` or like this `class Welcome extends Component`? because if is function component, is not `this.props.siteurl`. Is `props.siteurl`

Comment: added complete code

Comment: Try using `${reactHandler.props.siteurl}` instead of `${this.props.siteurl}`.

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: Nice! you see that is better to add more code than just a line :P. I wouldn't use ajax with react but that is up to you and offtopic

Comment: Thank you Mike,i will make a note of this for future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code:

```
url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Templates')/items?$select=Title,CurrentLink,HistoricalLink,DataGroupTemplate/Template&$expand=DataGroupTemplate&$filter=DataGroupTemplate/Template eq '${a}'`
```

**Update**:

Instead of `${this.props.siteurl}`, try using `${reactHandler.props.siteurl}`.

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: i tried it but not working throwing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: url:`${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/currentuser`,     working 

url:`${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserList')/items?$select=UserName/EMail,UserType&$filter=UserName/EMail eq '${currentuser}' &$expand=UserName`,   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: Are you using second(working) URL in same SPFx webpart?

Comment: yes i am using the same one to get current user email

Comment: Yes, But are you using it in same webpart(code file?)? Can you please add your complete code/function?

Comment: You can try to debugging, what are you getting in `this`??

Comment: added a code function i am using the same one to get variable a and current user name

Comment: Instead of `{this.props.siteurl}`, try using `{reactHandler.props.siteurl}`.

Comment: Thank you its working

Comment: Welcome, please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Done many thanks for this